# Dynamically changing a package in Common Lisp

Tags: package, common-lisp

I find myself changing packages a lot, so I decided to create a convenience symbol macro for myself to save some time:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage   :package
  (:nicknames p)
  (:export    :c)
  (:use       :cl))

(in-package :package)

(defun change-package ()
  (format t "package name > ")
  (let ((package-name (read)))
    (in-package package-name)))

(define-symbol-macro c (change-package))
```

I want to be able to type `p:c` in the REPL from within any package and change to package to the target package. The problem is that the in-package macro captures `package-name` and treats it as the name of the package.

I tried creating a macro of my own...

```
(defmacro ip (package-name)
  `(in-package ,package-name))

(defun change-package ()
  (format t "package name > ")
  (let ((package-name (read)))
    (ip package-name)))
```

... but of course that didn't work either, since the macro simply expands to the variable name anyway:

```
(setq package-name 'new-package)

(macroexpand '(ip package-name))

;; (EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL :LOAD-TOPLEVEL :EXECUTE)
;;  (SETQ *PACKAGE* (SB-INT:FIND-UNDELETED-PACKAGE-OR-LOSE "PACKAGE-NAME")))
T
```

**Questions**:

1. How can I pass the name of the package to the `in-package` macro so I can dynamically change the package?
2. If this is not possible, what would be the fastest (least keystrokes) way to achieve it? (I am aware that slime has `,` + `in-package` option)

Comment: "Where" do you want to change package ? In the REPL ? I'm not sure to really understand what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yes, I am using the REPL.

Comment: Why not just `(CL:SETF CL:*PACKAGE* ...your code here....)`

Comment: the Slime REPL has shortcuts to change packages (e.g. typing comma first I think it brings a menu if I recall correctly)

Comment: Other shortcut: from a .lisp file (not the REPL), `C-~` changes the current package of the REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `IN-PACKAGE` is a macro, it does not evaluate its arg.
- you can't write a macro, because they are expanded by the compiler BEFORE runtime

So either:

- Eval a new `IN-PACKAGE` form with the desired package. Use `EVAL`.
- just set `cl:*package*` to the desired package

Why is IN-PACKAGE a macro? -> it expands into an `EVAL-WHEN` form, making sure that there is a compile time side-effect when compiling a FILE